# Why I can't add an Object to an Object[] array?

Tags: java, arrays

I know I can use ArrayList for this, but I don't understand why I can't add an Object intance to the following Object[] array?

```
class Penguin {
    public void say(){
        System.out.println("Hi, I am a penguin!");
    }
}
public class TempTest {
    private Object[] items;
    private int next = 0;
    private int i = 0;
    public void add(Object x){
        if(next < items.length)
            items[next++] = x;
    }
    public boolean end() { return i == items.length; }
    public Object current() { return items[i]; }
    public void next() { if(i < items.length) i++; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] obj = new Object[5];
        Object p = new Penguin();
        obj.add(p);
    }
}
```

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

Comment: `TempTest#add` not `Object[]#add`

Comment: Why do you think an array (in Java) has an add method? Read some tutorials, please. The [Arrays chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) in the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) tells you more.

Comment: Indeed, I was too quick. Though I added `add` method it belongs to TempTest not Object[]. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays don't have an `add` function, you're thinking of Collections.

When you have an array of a specific size, you can set the indexes of that array:

```
Object[] arr = new Object[2];
arr[0] = /* your object */;

//...
Object yourObj = arr[0]; //returns that object
```

As pointed out by @SubhrajyotiMajumder , try calling your class' local implementation of the method:

```
this.add(yourObj);
```

And from there potentially refactor code so that you are editing the same array each time, not one that you made locally.

Comment: Arrays aren't data structures? I think you meant `Collection`.

Comment: @KepaniHaole Correct, slight slip on my part!

Comment: I wish I could access Penguin object with `arr[0].say();`

Comment: Don't make it an Object array, make it an array of some common interface that has the `say()` method :)

Answer (score 3):

Because `obj` is an *array*, you simply add elements by indexes:

```
obj[0] = someObject;
```

In your case, you should add elements using a loop, from 0 to 4.

See [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

`Object` class does not have any method called `add`. Its an array so u need to put objects using index.

Also creating an array of Object is not a good idea unless u really have a real need of doing so. Better use collections.

Answer (score 1):

[Assign value for an array](http://java.about.com/od/understandingdatatypes/a/Working-With-Arrays.htm)

```
obj[0] = p;
```

instead of

```
obj.add(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

`obj` is an array, you can add elements by

```
obj[0] = object1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention object array index there instead of add method .

obj [array index] = p ;